# SproutCore devs - What languages should you know well beforehand?

Tags: javascript, sproutcore

Hindsight is 20/20, eh? What programming languages do you think are most beneficial for a budding SproutCore dev to know?

And yes, I am totally incapabable of R'ingTF'ingM.

Answer (score 2):

Um, its a javascript framework.  So, um, javascript.  You really really really want to know javascript before delving into SC.

Also the build tools are written in ruby, so having ruby knowledge can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to know Cocoa you may recognize some of the mentality, but it's far from necessary to learn. I do happen to know Cocoa, but only learned it after learning SC. You'll definitely need to know JS and you'll also want to spend some time figuring out the SC way of doing things. If you have more questions, visit the IRC chat room at #sproutcore or check out the mailing list at sproutcore@googlegroups.com.